# How to get object value in Angular when brackets conflict?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have a weird situation: due to our Django backend, we changed our frontend Angular braces to brackets, but now I can't access an object value dynamically, for example:

```
<div>[[ house.basement ]]</div>
<div>[[ house.attic ]]</div>
```

The above works, but below would not:

```
<div>[[ house[floor] ]]</div>
```

Is there a straight-forward solution here? I can use a function to look for the floor, but it'd be much less efficient.

Here is my simplified controller:

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.floor = 'basement';
    $scope.house = {
      'basement': 'boo';
      'attic': 'yay';
    };
};
```

There's a radio button that controls floor model, but I don't think that's too relevant here.

*EDIT*

So based on comments, I was not being clear, I want to access the value of $scope.house based on how $scope.floor changes. This works perfectly fine in normal angular:

```
<div>{{ house[floor] }}</div>
```

And it would display 'boo'. The problem is because we changed braces to brackets, the interpreter breaks down and we're not sure how to escape properly.

Comment: Deleted my answer, I've never seen that construct through the angular helpers.

Comment: OP, time to dig the source code!

Comment: @WBC, WHY looking for trouble by changing angular's double curly notation? We use django on the server-side as well; just wrap you angular code with {% verbatim %}.

Comment: yeah I think our team will have to talk about the notation. I was actually using verbatim initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-bind.

```
<div ng-bind='house[floor]'></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/diL34NCmoUPcd3AZZ3jb?p=info